# Python CGIHTTPServer access denied on OS X

Tags: python-2.7, permissions, osx-mountain-lion, cgihttpserver

I get this error while trying to trigger a Python script inside CGI from the browser;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/CGIHTTPServer.py", line 251, in run_cgi
    os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [20/Apr/2013 14:51:16] CGI script exit status 0x7f00
```

I'm not running the main process as root (`$ python-32 main.py`).

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021369/python-cgihttpserver-crashes-with-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied) did not seem to work for me.

Making the script executable also didn't work (`$ chmod +x index.py`, `-rwxr-xr-x`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally got it to work. This is the basic script;

**index.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
print 'Content-Type: text/html\n\n'
print ''
print 'test'
```

**Requirements**

- The file needs to be executable; `$ chmod +x index.py`
- The file needs to have `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Hope it might help someone in the future.